# Fancy header for an onesided document

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I am trying to use the package `fancyhdr` for header and footer in my custom made template for writing thesis. 
There are lot of help to the `fancyhdr` queries on TeX.SE, but I could not find the solution to the below.

For an `oneside` document class, I need the header of the document to the something like this :

For an even numbered page:

```
page no.                                   Chapter.x ChapterTitle

(left corner)                               (right corner)

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

For an odd numbered page

```
Section.x (just number) SectionTitle           page no.                       

(left corner)                               (right corner)

-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is a minimal example of my thesis:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyfoot{}

\fancyhead[RO,LO]{\thepage}

\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}

\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\btypeout{\chaptername \ \thechapter.\ \space #1}\markboth{\@chapapp\ \thechapter.\ #1}{%
\@chapapp\ \thechapter.\ #1}}

\lhead[]{\fancyplain{}{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\section{Milky Way}
\lipsum
\section{Andromeda}
\lipsum
\chapter{Spectroscopy}
\section{Hubble}
\lipsum
\section{SALT}
\lipsum




\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example which shows how you are trying to use `fancyhdr`, in what context you are trying to use it and what, exactly, the obstacle is to your success. However, a one-sided document does not have different page layout for odd and even pages. All pages are odd for practical purposes because they are all on the right-hand side. So your question seems rather confused and unclear.

Comment: @cfr I have added the working example in the question. Hope this helps.

Comment: ***It makes no sense to have different headers and footers for odd and even pages in a one-sided document.***

Comment: How is `\btypeout` defined?

Comment: @cfr \newcommand\btypeout[1]{\bhrule\typeout{\space #1}\bhrule}

Comment: You should edit your code to correct it. This is why you should check an MWE really compiles before posting it ;).

Answer (score 4):

Why do you believe that you want a one-sided layout?

There are several possibilities.

1. You really intend to print single-sided. If so, then your layout makes no sense, but that is, after all, your business. Telling LaTeX you will print duplex doesn't commit you to anything. Just Go Ahead and Lie!
2. You do not want different sized margins.
3. You don't want blank pages when you start a new chapter.

All of these are perfectly compatible with telling LaTeX `twoside`. 2 and 3 don't even require you to lie about it.

On the other hand, if you say `oneside` then all pages get the same format. Sure, you could hack the output routine to check the page number and set the headers and footers accordingly, but that's just what `twoside` does anyway, so you might as soon use it.

The following satisfies 2 and 3. To satisfy 1, simply tell your printer to print single-sided. (Liar!) If your printer can't print duplex (and often even if it can), it will do this anyway. Saying `twoside` to LaTeX isn't saying anything to your printer. It only affects the default layout.

`openany` prevents empty pages before chapters. We load `geometry` with `hmarginration=1:1` to ensure symmetrical margins. `headheight=15pt` is required to accommodate the header. (Check the console output for the value `fancyhdr` needs - it will warn you if the setting is too small.)

And that's really it. Sure it is a `twoside` layout - that's how we get different headers for odd and even pages. In all other respects, it is just like `oneside`.

That is, you should want this, even if you thought you wanted something else because the something else would be a great deal more work and much more fragile, and would be no different in appearance or functionality. Better Lie!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage[headheight=15pt,hmarginratio=1:1]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhf[roh,leh]{\thepage}
\fancyhf[reh]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhf[loh]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\section{Milky Way}
\lipsum
\section{Andromeda}
\lipsum
\chapter{Spectroscopy}
\section{Hubble}
\lipsum
\section{SALT}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: two-sided layout for symmetry with no blanks]

Comment: I must confess that, yes, it doesn't make any sense to have different header and footer for one-sided document. Point 2 is what I need.  But, anyways, the above example was helpful. To add, I have set the margins using  \usepackage{vmargins}. How will be able to set same margins for even numbered pages?

Comment: I don't know `vmargins`. If you mean `vmargin`, don't use it. Use `geometry` instead. `vmargin` shouldn't be used in new code.

Comment: Sorry, it is vmargin. I could solve it using \usepackage{vmargin}. I added the following \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{3.5cm} \setlength{\evensidemargin}{3.5cm}. I will use geometry as you have mentioned. Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Really, you should not do that.`vmargin` causes problems. It is not at all a good approach. You are just storing up trouble for later. It will be easier to switch to `geometry`. Unless you are very close to a submission deadline for a long document e.g. your doctoral dissertation is due tomorrow. Then emergency hacks are probably best - you can deal with the fallout at your leisure. If it isn't a situation of that kind, though, it is better to avoid the fallout in the first place.

Comment: Okay. I am going to change it to geometry. Will post if there are any problems.

Answer (score 1):

I had one but with book documentclass, given below  It is explained page 10 of fancyhdr document. But MWE will give details of your documentclass.

```
\documentclass{book}



\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]%
{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]%
{\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\chaptername
        \ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase \leftmark}



\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents

    \chapter{First}
    \section{First within First}
    \lipsum
    \section{Second within First}
    \lipsum
    \chapter{Second}
    \section{First within Second}
    \lipsum
    \section{Second within Second}
    \lipsum




\end{document}
```

Comment: @RamaKrishnaMagesty This work perfectly for a two sided document. I want the same format to work in a one sided document too. How to do that?