# Problem with fancyhdr aligned text and show

Tags: fancyhdr

I am using the package fancyhdr to edit the header of my Phd Thesis.
I want the header to contain on (say) odd pages something like 
"CHAPTER 2. This is the second chapter" aligned to the left, 
while on even pages something like 
"2.5. This is the fifth section of the second chapter" aligned to the right.

So far, with the settings below, I manage to have the "CHAPTER 2. This is the second chapter" on both odd and even pages, with correct alignment.

I know it has to do with LE,RO and similar, but every time I change something, this results in both the Chapter title and the Section title to appear simultaneuosly on both even and odd pages with alignement switched 
(odd pages have chapter title on the left and section title on the right, while even pages have chapter title on the right and section title on the left)
The commented

> \renewcommand

and

> \fancyhead

lines are my tries at achieving this, 
but when doing this I get an error like "undefined control sequence "section"..." pointing to the first section of the whole document.

how can I modify my fancyhdr settings in order to achieve what I want?

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    \usepackage[dutch,english]{babel}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{lineno}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{feynmp}
    \usepackage{ifpdf}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \DeclareGraphicsRule{*}{mps}{*}{}
    \usepackage{epsfig}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\textsl{}}%\small\rightmark}}
    %\fancyhead[LE]{\textsl{}}%\small\rightmark}}
    %\fancyhead[RO]{\textsl{\small\leftmark}}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{\MakeUppercase{ \chaptername}\ \thechapter. \ #1}{}}
    %\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{ \markleft{\MakeUppercase{ \sectionname}\ \thesection. \ #1}{}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \lipsum
    \section{First section of first chapter}
    \section{Second section of first chapter}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: don't use `epsfig`. `hyperref` needs to be loaded LATE - last except for a couple of exceptions. Don't use `subfigure` as it is obsolete. Use `\fancyhf{}` to clear everything. Then `\fancyhf[loh]{left aligned on odd pages}` and `\fancyhf[reh]{right aligned on even pages}`.

Comment: Welcome, are you confusing right hand (odd) and left-hand (even) pages? Not using `fancyhdr` (so using default) gives, i think, what you want?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your replies, the default does indeed what I want, but with the title in CAPS and some sections have a long title, making the chapter title merge with the section title. In order to modify the appearance of the header I was advised to use fancyhdr . 
Mine was just an example (note the "say"), I would like to better understand how this package work, since I read the documentation for it but I couldn't find the answer to my specific question

Comment: @cfr what should i put within the curly brackets of the \fancyhf[loh/reh] command ? Is it something similar to

{\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{\MakeUppercase{ \chaptername}\ \thechapter. \ #1} }

Comment: I found a solution that does almost exactly what I want at
[link] (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/328864/fancy-header-for-an-onesided-document)... adding the \fancyhf[loh/reh] commands suggested by @cfr...How can I close this topic?

Comment: Best is if we close as a duplicate of the question which you found, I think. That way, this question will include a pointer there for people with similar questions in the future.